# How to add a event for a table within a TD of another table

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a table inside a TD of another table.
the parent TD has a function to be executed on clicking.
So how to add a event for the child table. I cant able to add a event for child table. The parent TD's  event is fired.

Comment: Please add relevant html and existing javascript code here, or make demo fiddle otherwise I doubt you will get an answer.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/979978) will help you.

Comment: would you please show your html code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wAtbJ)

HTML

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td class="outer">
            Outer

      <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="inner" >Inner</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$('.outer').click(function(){
  alert('test')
})

$('.inner').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```